# Forcing landscape orientation on devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, landscape, device

I do not have any code, as I simply do not know where to start with this but is it possible I assume using javaccript. But is it possible to force a website to be a landscape layout on all mobile devices including ipad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk no mate it's not but hopefully there is an answer there! Hehe

Comment: How is your question any different?

Comment: No different, I was merely saying it's not a duplicate in the sense that I haven't posted twice

Comment: You need to use "Phonegap/Cordova".